# Where is the binary of test_tf2_sensor_msgs?

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS package tf2_sensor_msgs (from the repo geometry2) comes with a test program

```
geometry2/tf2_sensor_msgs/test/test_tf2_sensor_msgs.cpp
```

I suppose this program can be  built and executed by `colcon test`. It works from my docker machine:

```
root@9da72d8e03df:~/ros2_ws# colcon test --packages-select tf2_sensor_msgs
Starting >>> tf2_sensor_msgs
Finished <<< tf2_sensor_msgs [0.05s]
```

Question: Where is the binary generated from `test_tf2_sensor_msgs.cpp`? I would need to invoke the generated binary from the command line without using `colcon` directly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369345/where-is-the-binary-of-test_tf2_sensor_msgs-?/) by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2021-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-12**:
I've updated the title of your question, as you're not looking for "the generated binary of colcon test", but for `test_tf2_sensor_msgs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I doubt that test is actually run, as `tf2_sensor_msgs` has everything related to testing commented out in its `CMakeLists.txt` ([here](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/99d87c508ba16743837910381775849110ffe52f/tf2_sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt#L28-L45)):

> ```
> # TODO enable tests
> ```

```
#if(BUILD_TESTING)
#  catkin_add_nosetests(test/test_tf2_sensor_msgs.py)
```

> ```
> #find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
> ```

```
#  sensor_msgs
#  rostest
#  tf2_ros
#  tf2
#)
#include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#add_executable(test_tf2_sensor_msgs_cpp EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/test_tf2_sensor_msgs.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(test_tf2_sensor_msgs_cpp ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})
#if(TARGET tests)
#  add_dependencies(tests test_tf2_sensor_msgs_cpp)
#endif()
#add_rostest(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test.launch)
#endif()
```

`tf2_geometry_msgs` does have testing enabled, and its binary can be found in `build/tf2_geometry_msgs/test_tf2_geometry_msgs` (`find /path/to/colcon_ws/build -executable  -type f | grep test`).

> I suppose this program can be built and executed by colcon test. It works from my docker machine:

As far as I know, `colcon test` only *runs* tests, it does not build them.

That would be `colcon build`'s job.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zhoulai Fu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34164/zhoulai-fu/) on 2021-01-13**:
Just for the record, tf2_geometry_msgs and tf2_sensor_msgs are actually two different packages:-)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-14**:
Yes, of course.

I was aware of that, but wanted to point you to a test which *is* being built and executed.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2021-01-14**:
You will get an entry like that when it runs "all" tests for a package. If the number of tests is zero you'll still get progress that tests for that package started and finished. You can turn on more verbosity or look a the test results or reports to see what was actually run.